# Pearson's r over time

Tags: meta-analysis, pearson-r

I have a Pearson's r for the same variables for 4 different periods of time. (4 different years). How can I find the Pearson's r for all of them put together? Here are the years and the related coefficients: `1969: -.169, 1975: .427, 1982: .308, 2006: .632`.  **Can I average these to the overall Pearson's r coefficient?**

Answer (score 3):

Not in general. You must pool the raw data. Think of it this way: each correlation is based on means and standard deviations of each subset; the overall correlation must be based on means and standard deviations for the entire set. The means and standard deviations for subsets were washed out in calculating the individual correlations.

Your example in which the individual correlations range from -0.169 to 0.632 is troubling. It seems unlikely that an overall correlation will mean much, as the relationship is changing markedly in direction as well as strength over your time period. You are probably doing this any way, but the corresponding scatter plots, both superimposed and juxtaposed, are likely to be much more revealing.

Comment: I like most of this answer but not the 4th sentence; are you sure you meant that?

Comment: Yes. I mean that no trace of them remains in the correlations. You give me a correlation, and I cannot guess the means and SDs on which it is based; hence, for example, I cannot reconstruct the overall mean from the correlations. The statement that you need the original data is the crucial statement and I am trying to explain why informally.

Comment: i don't have access to spss to compute the set now, but I do have the outputs, the means and std deviations. what is the formula? is it difficult to do? I am writing a research paper. would it be better to just report the coefficient for each year and then include the scatter plot graphs because I have those as well?

Comment: That information is not sufficient any more than two means and two SDs are sufficient to define one correlation. I said "based on the means and standard deviations", but the covariance is not defined by the means and SDs and you need the raw data too.

Comment: My guess from what you say is that an overall correlation would not mean much and that statistical reviewers would be likely to say so.